# using dplyr for filtering

Tags: dplyr, filter

can someone help me to find the mistake in the following code? I got the error:
"column1 - column3 > 0: non-numeric argument to binary operator"

```
fct <- function(column1, column2, column3){
filter(column2 <0 && column1-column3 >0) %>%
select(column1, column2, column3)%>%
}
```

thanks

Comment: For R code, consider creating a reproducible example (https://reprex.tidyverse.org) to make it easier to debug. In your case, I assume you intend to use filter and select from the dplyr package, but when your function is called dplyr is not loaded and stats::filter is used instea. Make sure to load dplyr beforehand or use the notation `dplyr::filter()`. Also note that the first argument needs to be a data.frame, not a column. You may need to read this: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 0):

1. 

I tried to reproduce your code but I got a different error message:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"    select(column1, column2, column3) %>% 
}"
```

I believe this is because of the pipe operator after the select statement.

2. For the kind of error you reported, a fix would be:

```
fct <- function(column1, column2, column3){
filter(column2 <0 && (column1-column3) >0) %>%
select(column1, column2, column3)
}
```

Without `$()`, R first performs the operation `$ column3>0` which returns a binary output. Hence we get an error because `$column1` is not binary.